# TFS 2015 Code Viewer Not Working in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tfs

I found the following issue here in stackoverflow however cannot comment as yet.  I have a similar issue and wonder if there is anyone out there that has solved it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917501/tfs-2015-web-portal-code-viewer-not-working#

I am encountering similar here. In house TFS 2015, can't view code in the web portal using Google Chrome however IE is fine. I, however, am not using HTTPS so may be experiencing something slightly different.

When I do try to view a file in Chrome, the window where the code listing should be is simply blank. I did note too that the button for creating a new build definition appears to be indicating a broken image link.

This has not always been an issue. Around 4 months ago I could get the code view fine in Chrome and, to my knowledge as I have no access to the servers, nothing has changed apart from Chrome updates.

I've tried getting to previous versions of Chrome to no avail, though I wouldn't know which version I was on when this did work.

Interestingly, I have one or two .MD files around and these display perfectly well. They are simple text files. However when saved with .TXT extension (or anything else I've tried), they do not show. Curious.

---

**Update**

As you will see from the screenshot below, when selection on a file has been made, in this case a .SQL file, where I would expect the view to populate nothing at all appears.

As for the F12, I do get 5 of these:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

plus associated paths of course.  We use Webroot internally here which has recently dropped in a Chrome extension however even when Webroot is disabled in its entirety (including removal of extension) I get the same behaviour.

All other Chrome extensions have been removed too at varying times to try to give a clean browser.

I have no other pop up blockers, ad blockers, etc installed on the workstation.

[image]

---

Comment: Did you try to use another account to connect to web portal? And did this issue only occurs on your dev machine or occurs on everyone in your team?

Comment: Everyone that can connect to the web portal has the same issue with Chrome.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show how it not working? And press F12 key, did you see any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to the F12 key suggestion.

After some grovelling I was granted domain admin privs to have a dig around everything.  It turns out that TFS was installed on ServerA with a URL port of 8080, this I knew from the original install and obviously the path I follow to get to my TFS web interface.  What had also been done subsequently, with no consultation of the Dev user group, was that a second TFS application tier had been installed on ServerB, the port here was 8088.

I had not noticed the difference in path initially, assuming it was Chrome or workstation related.  Anyway, I altered the port on ServerB to 8080 and everything jumped into life.  I should not have made assumptions and should have paid more attention to the path in the error!

It seems the second application tier was set up on a non-production environment to allow senior Dev users access to the TFS Management Console rather than allowing them access to the original app tier which was on a production box.  Our IT Operations just forgot to tell anyone.

Comment: Glad to hear the issue solved. You could mark it as an answer, which will also help others in this site later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your chrome to latest version of (55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)).

Also clear the cache of chrome. I have also encountered similar issues. The solution is clear cache and connect to the web portal use another ID, then connect back use the original ID. I have no idea which one solved the problem. You could try both.

This problem should only be an individual phenomenon, since TFS2015 has been released for a long time.

Comment: Chrome is (and was) on the latest version.  I cleared the cache and connected with my user ID, no joy.  I cleared the cache, connected with another user ID then back to my own ID, again, with no joy.